# Convergence of random varaible?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I was reading notion of convergence in random variables and I am not sure if I understood them correctly. According to Wikipedia, for sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...$, almost sure convergence means $P(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n = X)=1$ which is same as $P(\omega \in \Omega : lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega))= 1 $. Now as random variables are function from sample space to $R$, then it seems almost sure convergence means that we have pointwise convergence of functions($X_n$'s to $X$'s) except for may be at sets of measure zero? Now I can see how this implies convergence in distribution but how about random variable $Y=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n$ and $X$, can we say $Y=X$? I can not see how this is true. Because although we have same functions(random variables), underlying randomness(which could be different for Y and X) could generate different $\omega$'s which could then be mapped by $Y$ and $X$ to different values in $R$. Also if this is not true then how is almost sure convergence different from convergence in distribution? Can we have some non-trivial example where the limiting random variable is not constant. I don't have mathematics background so please try to avoid measure theoretic language and sorry for the long and confusing post. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you define $Y = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n$ (assuming the limit exists) then indeed $Y=X$ almost surely.  It does not make sense to say "underlying randomness is different for $Y$ and $X$" since we have $Y(\omega)$ and $X(\omega)$.  They are defined for the same $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: An example of convergence in distribution is if $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d Gaussian $N(0,1)$.  Then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X_1$ (it does not converge almost surely).   An example of almost sure convergence is if $Z_n= X_1 + 1/n$ for all $n$, then indeed $Z_n\rightarrow X_1$ almost surely (in fact, surely).  Another example is $W_n = X_1 + X_n/n$, then indeed $W_n\rightarrow X_1$ almost surely (but not surely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y$ is another limit with probability $1$ then $X =Y$ with probability $1$, that is $P(X\not = Y)=0$, that is, there is a subset of $\Omega$ whose probability is $0$ and if we omit this set then we can say that $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ (not in that set).

As far as the relationship between the two concept of convergence. Take a specific example over $\Omega=[0,1]$. Let the probability measure be uniform (fined by the length). Consider $X(\omega)=\omega$. This is going to be the limiting random variable. And define the $X_n$s as functions from $[0,1]$ to $R$ the following "walking" way. First divide $[0,1]$ into four subintervals: $[0,1/4],(1/4,1/2],(1/2,3/4],(3/4,1]$.   Let $X_1=0$ over $[0,1/4]$ and $\omega$ otherwise. Let $X_2=0$ over $(1/4,1/2]$ and $\omega$ otherwise and so on. Then halve these intervals and define $X_5=0$ over $[0,1/8]$ and $\omega$ otherwise. Then let the abyss "walk" through the $8$ intervals.

The figure below depicts $X_{10}$ and $X_{11}$ the $10$th and the $11$th elements of this walking abyss.

[image]

Then halve the current intervals and let walk the next series the similar way. Then halve again. Now, you are going to have narrower and narrower abysses walking through the interval $[0,1]$. The probability that $X_n=\omega$ is getting larger and larger because the interval over which $X_n$ is $0$ is getting narrower and narrower. So, this is convergence in distribution to $X=\omega$. Do  we have convergence with probability $1$? No! Because for any $\omega$ there will be always an $n$ for which the slimmer and slimmer walking abyss will make $X_n=0$ for that $\omega$. 
What is more, $P(\lim X_n(\omega)=\omega)=0$.

Comment: This example is way too complicated to just show convergence in distribution holds but not almost sure convergence.  In fact this example is showing a more complex situation where convergence "in probability" holds but not almost surely.

Comment: @Michael: OK.  Right. But I don't agree with the "way too complicated" part.

Comment: Compared to an iid sequence of Gaussian variables $N(0,1)$?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, right. My reason to add the more complicated and way deeper example is that, in my opinion the OP were having something like this in mind. But, yes. If you take the question word by word then you are very right.

Comment: This is certainly an important and deeper example. (+1 for that, and nice picture).

Comment: @zoli Thanks for the beautiful example. I can see it does not have the almost sure convergence according to the definition. But I guess my confusion is this, definition just says that the functions(random variable) converge in probability but what if I have different probability space ($(\Omega,F,P_1)$  and $(\Omega,F,P_2)$ then can we say $Y=X$. And even if they have the same probability space, how I see things is that first  a random event occurs and then that event is mapped to R using random variable(which is nothing but a function).

Comment: @zoli continue:  Now my confusion is that even if we have same random variable underlying random event could be different. Sorry I think I am completely confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1131274 (beautiful name :) : Wait, wait. I am here to dissolve the confusion. So, if the probability measure changes then all these definitions lose their meaning. Don't change the probability distribution.

Comment: @user1131274 : Your last comment seems to be similar to saying "If $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are iid can we say $X_1=X_2$?"

Comment: @zoli ok. So in a way are we saying that the underlying generation of random events(from the probability space) is common for all the variables involved while talking about these things and only thing that differs are random variable(or so called mappings from $\Omega$ to R)? Thanks again.

Comment: @Michael if $X_i$'s are iid then $X_1=X_2$ will not be true right? It looks like we will only have convergence in distribution in this case. Does my last comment make sense?

Comment: Yes, your last comment seems to be concluding the same as my initial comment on "they are defined for the same $\omega \in \Omega$."  In general, the statement "$X=Y$" means that $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.  Note that if $\{X_i\}$ are iid then a single $\omega$ determines all the values $X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega), X_3(\omega),...$, and often $X_1(\omega) \neq X_2(\omega)$. [Apologies to Zoli for all my comments cluttering up his answer.]